# Disable dates + weekday numbers with flatpickr

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, flatpickr

I would like to be able to deactivate days + weekday numbers 1 to 7.

```
calendar.flatpickr({
                        disable: dateUnvailableCalendar,
                        minDate: "today",
                        onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr) {
                            calendarHandleChange(dateStr);
                        }
                    });
```

This is what I have already done. this disable days i send in an array.
now i wish i could disable day number 5 and 7 of every week of the whole year.
Do you know how I can do this please?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
flatpickr("#myDatePicker", {
  disable: [
    function(date) {
      // saturdays
      return date.getDay() === 6;
    },
    function(date) {
      // sundays
      return date.getDay() === 0;
    }
  ]
});
```

[Disabling range of dates](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#disabling-ranges-of-dates)

[Disabling specific dates](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#disabling-specific-dates)

To disable dates that are in an array:

```
var dates = ["2025-01-30", "2025-02-21", "2025-03-08", new Date(2025, 4, 9) ];
flatpickr("#myDatePicker", {
  disable: dates
});
```

In your case, for specific dates and Saturdays:
I suppose that in 'dateUnavailableCalendar' you will have an array of dates.

```
flatpickr("#myDatePicker", {
  disable: [
    function(date) {
      return date.getDay() === 6;
    },
    dateUnavailableCalendar
    
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback however this will just block number 6 and 0 but I would also like to add dates which are in a table.

Comment: @CHRISCOM In that case I had left you a link to the documentation for specific dates, anyway I edit the answer so you can disable the dates that are in an array.

Comment: but is it possible to deactivate specific dates + every Tuesday and Thursday of the year? Thx

Comment: @CHRISCOM of course, just use multiple functions in the disable array, I edited the answer so you can disable the dates and saturdays

Comment: I tried what you told me to do but it doesn't score because I think my dates are already in an array. I put you the console.log of my array of dates.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution however in dynamic mode it does not work. Here is the solution:

```
disable: [
                            function(date) {
                                return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
                            },
                            {
                                'from': '2023-03-06',
                                'to' : '2023-03-13'
                            },
                            {
                                'from': '2023-03-21',
                                'to' : '2023-03-21'
                            }
                        ],
```

do you have any idea how i can convert my json to look like my example?
I tried the JSON.stringify but the json comes out with [] and it is not interpreted.
Thank you.

console.log(dateUnvailableCalendar);

[image: array]