# convert array to javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an array that looks like this:

```
var dateUnvailableCalendar = {{ datesUnvailable|json_encode|raw }};
```

[image: array]

and I want to transform it to look like this:

```
{
    'from': '2023-03-06 00:00',
    'to': '2023-03-13 00:00'
},
{
    'from': '2023-03-01 00:00',
    'to': '2023-03-01 00:00'
}
```

do you know how i could do this please?

Thank you for help.

WORK

```js
calendar.flatpickr({
  disable: [
    function (date) {
      return date.getDay()===dayWeek[0]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[1]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[2]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[3]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[4]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[5]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[6]
    },
    {
      'from': '2023-03-06 00:00',
      'to': '2023-03-13 00:00'
    },
    {
      'from': '2023-03-01 00:00',
      'to': '2023-03-01 00:00'
    }
  ],
  minDate: "today",
  onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr) {
    calendarHandleChange(dateStr);
  }
});
```

in this example the dates that will be deactivated will be those that are in the function.

```
calendar.flatpickr({
                        disable: [
                            function(date) {
                                return date.getDay() === dayWeek[0] ||
                                    date.getDay() === dayWeek[1] ||
                                    date.getDay() === dayWeek[2] ||
                                    date.getDay() === dayWeek[3] ||
                                    date.getDay() === dayWeek[4] ||
                                    date.getDay() === dayWeek[5] ||
                                    date.getDay() === dayWeek[6]
                            },
                            [
                                {"from":"2023-03-06 00:00","to":"2023-03-13 00:00"},
                                {"from":"2023-03-01 00:00","to":"2023-03-01 00:00"}
                            ]
                        ],
                        minDate: "today",
                        onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr) {
                            calendarHandleChange(dateStr);
                        }
                    });
```

do you know why it doesn't work sending the array to it?

Comment: What you want to change it do does not make sense. It already does look like that because it's an array with a list of objects as values. You can't have a list of objects without having them in an array or some list structure you create.

Comment: Your examples are just two different representations of the same thing. If you want to get the output example _as a string for display_ you could `JSON.stringify` the array, but it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have to be able to do it this way because I use flatpickr to disable dates that come from this variable + weekday dates -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75579599/disable-dates-weekday-numbers-with-flatpickr/75579660?noredirect=1#comment133361917_75579660

Comment: Your from/to dates are **already in an array**. Therefore you can just use it directly as such; you don't need to make it into another array.

Comment: The input isn't an array, it looks like it may be some template system markup which in the browser *becomes* an array?  The expected output is *almost* an array, it's just missing the square brackets to enclose the items.  It's really not clear what the problem is or what you're trying to accomplish.  (Or what this has to do with jQuery?)  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates hard-coded input and what you're attempting to do with that input?

Comment: if I send this (see above) back to flapickr it works. on the other hand if I return the array in the other way it does not work.

Comment: @CHRISCOM: We don't know what you mean by "send this" or "it works" or "return the array in the other way" or "it does not work".  I'm afraid you're going to have to clarify the problem in order for anybody to help.  As it currently stands, it just sounds like you have a misunderstanding of one or more JavaScript concepts and may not be experiencing any actual problem.

Comment: I've detailed above what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at what you're doing here:

```
disable: [
  function(date) { /*...*/ },
  dateUnvailableCalendar
]
```

What is `dateUnvailableCalendar`?  Is it an array?  If so then the resulting structure is this:

```
disable: [
  function(date) { /*...*/ },
  []
]
```

That is, this `disable` property is an array with two elements, one of which is a function and the other of which is another array.

It sounds like you want to append the *contents* of this `dateUnvailableCalendar` array to create one larger array.  You can use the spread operator, for example:

```
disable: [
  function(date) { /*...*/ },
  ...dateUnvailableCalendar
]
```

---

**Edit:** The functionality is demonstrated here:

```js
let calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');
let dayWeek = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];

let calendarHandleChange = (dateStr) => {
  console.log(dateStr);
}
let dateUnvailableCalendar = [{
    'from': '2023-03-06 00:00',
    'to': '2023-03-13 00:00'
},
{
    'from': '2023-03-01 00:00',
    'to': '2023-03-01 00:00'
}];

calendar.flatpickr({
  disable: [
    function(date) {
      return date.getDay() === dayWeek[0] ||
        date.getDay() === dayWeek[1] ||
        date.getDay() === dayWeek[2] ||
        date.getDay() === dayWeek[3] ||
        date.getDay() === dayWeek[4] ||
        date.getDay() === dayWeek[5] ||
        date.getDay() === dayWeek[6]
    },
    ...dateUnvailableCalendar // <--- spreading the array here
  ],
  minDate: "today",
  onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr) {
    calendarHandleChange(dateStr);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<input id="calendar" />
```

(Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75596944/328193) for providing the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that the OP refuses to.)

Comment: i tried your solution but it doesn't work :( this by loop

Comment: @CHRISCOM: What "doesn't work" about it?  What is the result you're looking to achieve?  How does this result differ from that?  Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and clarify specifically what problem you are observing.

Comment: Here's the code that doesn't work retrieving the dateUnvailableCalendar variable.

Comment: @CHRISCOM: You forgot to include any actual code with your comment.  Though keep in mind that code in comments is generally unreadable, beyond a simple expression or statement.  Please update the question with information relevant to the question.

Comment: I edited the question. Do you understand the request?

Comment: @CHRISCOM: So now you're indicating that using an array of functions/objects as the `disable` property "works", but *nesting* arrays in that property "doesn't work".  Which I'd expect.  And which is *exactly* what this answer indicates.  (Though the actual implementation of it depends entirely on whatever `dateUnvailableCalendar` is, which we don't know.)  There continues to be no actual problem to solve here, just an ongoing misunderstanding on your part on what an array is.

Comment: I indicated the return of the dateUnvailableCalendar variable,

Comment: @CHRISCOM: And assuming you're not mistaken in that information, the approach in this answer demonstrably works.  I've added a code snippet to illustrate.  (Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75596944/328193) for providing a [mcve].)  Spreading an array does *exactly* what you're asking.  Whatever attempt you've made that you aren't showing which "doesn't work" may have other problems that we don't (can't) know about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252208/discussion-between-chriscom-and-david).

Comment: @CHRISCOM: Let's not.  Let's instead give *you* time to create a running [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you're facing.  Because you currently have *two working solutions*, both of which demonstrate their effectiveness with an [mcve].  Whether you say "it doesn't work" in a question, or in comments, or in chat... it makes no difference.  "It doesn't work" isn't an answerable question.

Comment: I found why it doesn't work! The problem came from the variable. @David your solution its work ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

**Works on more than 2 elements of `dateUnvailableCalendar`**

Your problem will be solved if you try to use the index of `dateUnvailableCalendar` in flatpickr disable property (e.g. `dateUnvailableCalendar[0]`). Try this:

```js
let calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');
let dayWeek = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];

let calendarHandleChange = (dateStr) => {
  console.log(dateStr);
}
let dateUnvailableCalendar = [{
    'from': '2023-03-06 00:00',
    'to': '2023-03-13 00:00'
},
{
    'from': '2023-03-01 00:00',
    'to': '2023-03-01 00:00'
},
{
    'from': '2023-03-22 00:00',
    'to': '2023-03-23 00:00'
}];

calendar.flatpickr({
  disable: [
    function (date) {
      return date.getDay()===dayWeek[0]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[1]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[2]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[3]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[4]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[5]||
        date.getDay()===dayWeek[6]
    }
  ].concat(dateUnvailableCalendar),
  minDate: "today",
  onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr) {
    calendarHandleChange(dateStr);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<input id="calendar" />
```

Comment: I tried this the problem is that dateUnvailableCalendar can have more than 2 elements.

Comment: You can solve that problem with the code above

Comment: the function which is in disable is a function specific to flatpickr.

Comment: It's a more roundabout way to do the same thing I propose in my answer, but working code is working code.  (I also borrowed the structure of your *very useful* code snippet to demonstrate my own approach.)